# Screensaver started and locked the "guest account" and asks for password.

Tags: password

I were logged in as a guest user on Ubuntu 12.04. I left the computer for a while and when I came back the screensaver had started, and locked the computer. Now it asks for a password to log in to the guest account. I don't have to write a password when I logged in as guest. How do I enter my current guest session without restarting the computer?

Answer (score 1):

Press "Switch User" and then log in from there.

Answer (score 1):

If the round-trip via "Switch User" brings you back to the password prompt as in Kubuntu after suspend2RAM, login as root and issue the following to a console:

```
$ users
```

will print the eligible login-names currently logged in.

```
$ sudo passwd guest-SLHiTY
```

Of course you must adjust the random letters at the end to your temporary guest account. Next you are asked for the root password. Thereafter you can specify a new guest password and repeat it.

Now switch back to the guest session (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd> or <kbd>F8</kbd>) and use the new password to get back into the guest session. It seems impossible to give an empty password this way but any three letters will do. Of course the new Password will be forgotten once you log out the guest, as this will completely remove the guest altogether.